# How to remove app from background programmatically in ios

Tags: ios

I want to terminate app as well as remove from background state

Comment: you can't remove app from background unless apple provide API

Comment: Your app or some other app?

Comment: you can relaunch your app programmatically in `applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)` method of AppDelegate.

Comment: I don't think such API is available to terminate app programmatically from background. Apple have strict policy regarding to Fetch from background. You can terminate through pragmatically.

Comment: What if you crash it ?

Comment: I just wanted to remove the app from background after calling the exit(0) funcation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to send a silent notification and upon getting the notification calling `exit(0)` in you code but I will recommend against this as it will not pass Apple review.

Answer (score 0):

I would never suggest you to do this but there is a key you can add in `info.plist` under "Application does not run in background". Setting it to `YES` will terminate app as soon as it goes into background.

In raw plist that should be:

```
<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: I have not checked this out, but if you say that anytime app is in background its terminated, then it might not work for all uses.

Comment: @GoodSp33d Maybe your question is missing some information. If you wish to simply terminate your app it is easiest to crash it "by mistake". Just do something like `let text: String! = nil; print(text.count)`